# The power and the force of an engine

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A car moves on an inclined plane with an angle whose sine is $\frac{1}{40}$ with uniform velocity 10 m/s against resistances 1225 N .Find the power of the engine .and if the power increased suddenly to 50 horse find the force of the engine .
My turn:
$$mg \sin{\theta} + R = F$$
$$F = 2450 N$$, $$P = F\times V= 2450\times 10=24500 watt$$
After the increasing of the power $$P' = F' \times V$$
$$50\times 735 = F'\times 10, F'= 3675 N$$
My question : 
Is it correct to use the equation :
The new power = the new force \times the old velocity ?

Comment: Uniform velocity means no net force, so the propelling force must be equal in magnitude and applied opposite to the resistance force of 1225N.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the power at any given time is the force times the velocity at the time given. In this situation, the increase in power will cause the car to accelerate up the incline.  As the velocity increases—if the power remains constant—both the acceleration and force will decrease, but right at the instant when the power increases, the force will increase to the value you have calculated.